# cookies or cache? my own site won't load in FF without a restarting FF

Tags: firefox

Over the last few days, I've noticed that (occasionally) when testing my own site in FF, it loads the first time that FF has been opened, but it seems to hang on subsequent loads (windows only - i haven't noticed this behaviour on mac, but i don't use my mac as much).

The url is http://HearWhere.com

Of course, my concern is that sometimes people will try to get to the site and not be able to (and based on what I can see, that is a distinct possibility, as i've seen a significant drop in stats over the last few days, so I suspect that might be happening).

Any idea why? I can't seem to figure this one out.

I view source on the page that hasn't loaded, and it appears that all the source is there.

The one thing I can think of that might be causing the problem is that in my head and footer, i have a bit of PHP which attaches the correct API key based on the visiting domain (this is so I don't have to hard-code the api key into the page and change it from dev to prod). 
i use a fairly simple

```
$domain=$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
if($domain=='dev'){
    $apiKey='apikey';
}else {
    $apiKey='apikey2';
}
```

but when viewing the source, it appears that show without issue. 
I do a similar bit of code at the bottom of the page so I only include tracking codes when the domain is not dev.

Any ideas?

UPDATE --------------------------------------------------------------------
After checking it out in Firebug (not sure why i didn't check that before), the following two google scripts are failing, and everything stops there. 
The site is map/location centric, so there i need the google stuff. Any idea why it would fail? 
these are the failing scripts
http://gg.google.com/csiv=2&s=mapsapi&action=jsloaderjslinker&rt=jsload.69,jseval.103,jsdone.105
http://gg.google.com/csi?v=2&s=mapsapi&action=apiboot&rt=d.2,e.316,ab1.336

Comment: Hmm strange. Filing under 'works for me'.

Comment: yeah, that's what i was afraid of. i've noticed it MANY times, but not consistently. And closing and re-opening firefox means it works perfectly. Even if i try to reload the page 4 or 5 times (while it isn't loading), it won't load. restart firefox and all is good. I was hoping a problem in my code.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) plugin for Firefox? It could help you debug some script/network/html issues.

You can [monitor](http://getfirebug.com/net.html) script, images and other ressources load time.

Good luck.

Comment: Just checked in firebug (sorry),  204 No Content from http://gg.google.com/csiv=2&s=mapsapi&action=jsloaderjslinker&rt=jsload.69,jseval.103,jsdone.105, and http://gg.google.com/csi?v=2&s=mapsapi&action=apiboot&rt=d.2,e.316,ab1.336. 
now..why?

Answer (score 0):

It appears this was/is an error with Firebug. Disabling firebug resolves the issue, so it shouldn't affect too many visitors.

Thanks for the help, 
Pete